# Remove package and module name from sphinx function

Tags: python-sphinx

it's any way to remove the package and or module name from sphinx doc?

Example: if exist a function called waa inside the module foo.bar, the rst code

```
.. automodule:: foo.bar
    :members:
```

will generate

```
foo.bar.waa()
```

and i want to output

```
waa()
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can change `add_module_names` to `False` in the file `conf.py`:

```
# If true, the current module name will be prepended to all description
# unit titles (such as .. function::).
add_module_names = False
```

Then `foo.bar.my_function()` will display as `my_function()`.

Comment: is there a way to do this per-automodule, rather than at the conf.py level?

Comment: This does it for the function/module/class itself, but not for arguments with type annotations. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/51394955/965332

Comment: To do it for specific objects and not globally, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74078513/939364

Answer (score 3):

I have [a package with submodules](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/web3-ethereum-defi#make) and I wanted to still display the submodule name in navigation, as there are multiple duplicate function names across submodules.

For

```
foo.bar.baz()
```

I need to display

```
bar.baz()
```

This makes

- Navigation is easier as everything does not start with the same letter from the package name
- Shorter names are more readable without repeating

For this, I created a custom Jinja filter and then modified autosummary's core templates to use it. The filter is injected through a monkey-patch in Sphinx's conf.py.

An example conf.py:

```py
# Monkey-patch autosummary template context
from sphinx.ext.autosummary.generate import AutosummaryRenderer


def smart_fullname(fullname):
    parts = fullname.split(".")
    return ".".join(parts[1:])


def fixed_init(self, app, template_dir=None):
    AutosummaryRenderer.__old_init__(self, app, template_dir)
    self.env.filters["smart_fullname"] = smart_fullname


AutosummaryRenderer.__old_init__ = AutosummaryRenderer.__init__
AutosummaryRenderer.__init__ = fixed_init
```

Then here is the example from `_templates/autosummary/module.rst`:

```
{{ fullname | smart_fullname | escape | underline}}

Documentation for `{{ fullname }}` module.

.. automodule:: {{ fullname }}
```

[See the full documentation for further examples](https://web3-ethereum-defi.readthedocs.io/api/index.html).