# Sphinx: Remove package and module name for specific function

Tags: python, python-sphinx

My question is very similar to the one here: [Remove package and module name from sphinx function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864406/remove-package-and-module-name-from-sphinx-function)

Is there a way to remove/hide package and module names in sphinx only for a single function or at least for each function in a file (basically changing the global conf.py settings locally), meanwhile they are displayed for the rest of the project?

I've looked for options, like the ones for automodule (:members:, :undoc-members: etc.), but I couldn't find any directive to hide this information.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74078513/939364

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use reST markup for [cross referencing syntax](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/domains.html#cross-referencing-syntax) like so:

> If you prefix the content with `~`, the link text will only be the last component of the target. For example,
>
> `` :py:meth:`~Queue.Queue.get` ``
>
> will refer to `Queue.Queue.get` but only display `get` as the link text.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works well if I want to reference the function somewhere. Does that work somehow for the autodoc directive (.. autofunction:: package1.subpack1.subpack2.mymodule1.function1). The generated line for the function is huge, it would make sense to hide package and subpackage names there.

Comment: AFAIK, you can set this globally with [add_module_names](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/config.html#confval-add_module_names), but not on a per-file or -function basis. You might look into post-processing the output.