# sphinx remove module prefix for args in automodule

Tags: python, python-sphinx, pybind11

I know how to remove the module prefix for functions in automodule directive by set "add_module_names = False".  [Remove package and module name from sphinx function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864406/remove-package-and-module-name-from-sphinx-function)

However it can't remove the module prefix for the args in automodule directive. Below is the document generated by automodule.

you can see the data type of self arg has a long prefix like "PyPhysLeo.data_core".

---

data_core submodule

class BufferDataD
a class which manage CPU buffer and GPU buffer simultaneously, data type is double

CPU2GPU(self: PyPhysLeo.data_core.BufferDataD) → None

GPU2CPU(self: PyPhysLeo.data_core.BufferDataD) → None

allocateCPU(self: PyPhysLeo.data_core.BufferDataD) → None

allocateGPU(self: PyPhysLeo.data_core.BufferDataD) → None

setZeroCPU(self: PyPhysLeo.data_core.BufferDataD) → None

setZeroGPU(self: PyPhysLeo.data_core.BufferDataD) → None

size(self: PyPhysLeo.data_core.BufferDataD) → int

Comment: Do you actually have "self" in the output? `self` is the conventional name of the implicit first argument of an instance method. Usually it is not shown in documentation.

Comment: @mzjn I check the output of "help(PyPhysLeo.data_core.BufferDataD)" in python interpreter, it has the self arg. Actually, module PyPhysLeo is a module created by pybind11. So maybe I need to search relative information about pybind11 rather than sphinx. It is not a problem with sphinx

Comment: @mzjn  this is because the pybind11 will automatically generate function signature . But what it generates is the tedious one, and the sphinx just bring it out. Now I     
    //disable auto function signature in module init process
    py::options options;
    options.disable_function_signatures();          Then sphinx behave as what I want. I think I need to close this question, thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

The signatures generated by pybind11 always are long and tedious(has self arg, type may has long module prefix). So the best way is to disable these signatures by adding code `py::options options;options.disable_function_signatures();` to your module init function. Then you need to write your own signature in the first line of the docstring like

```
setZeroGPU() -> None

    reset GPU buffer data to zero

    :return: None
    :rtype: None
```

setZeroGPU() -> None is the signature and it is in the first line.

Because "autodoc_docstring_signature" in conf.py is set to True by default, sphinx will automatically try to read function signature from the first line of docstring. At last, you can get a beautiful document like this.

```
setZeroGPU() → None
    reset GPU buffer data to zero

    返回: None
    返回类型:   None
```

Comment: Could you add more detail? How do you specifically add the `py::options options;options.disable_function_signatures();` to the init function?