# Customizing style of function name in LaTeX

Tags: python, latex, customization, python-sphinx

I'm trying to use Sphinx to autogenerate a code report in LaTeX. I have a file named install.py which has the function "function_example". In the rst file I have:

```
.. automodule:: install
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:
```

and then what shows up in the pdf is:

[image: pdf screenshot]

I've been able to change most of the document's layout, but that's the one thing I couldn't change, the `install.function_exemple(par_a, par_b)` output on my pdf. I'd like to make it bold and change its color. Also, it would be great to get rid of the `install` and only have `function_exemple(par_a, par_b)` on the pdf.

Comment: To get rid of the `install` module name, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/20864406/407651

Comment: thanks for the link @mzjn ! and for the style, yeah it's latex. I've added a few .sty files and could pretty much customize everything in the document, except for this function call :/